# SQL Foreign key that checks concatenated string data

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I have a table `Shops` with column `Products` and a table `ShopProducts` with a column `Name`.

The point of the `Products` column is to list all `ShopProducts` the shop sells, as a comma-separated string. I want to verify that all the products in said column exist in table `Shop Products`. Is it possible to have a foreign key that will verify data in the format of "Pizza, croissant" is valid if in table `ShopProducts` exist records with name "Pizza" and "croissant"?

Comment: "comma-separated string"  -->  **broken data model**.  Fix your data model.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, why, though? If I just need it as a string to display, isn't it OK? How would you advise me to fix it in, anyway (I got curious).

Comment: If you "just" need as a string to display, you wouldn't need a foreign key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, untrue, I want to make sure the elements of the string actually exist.

Comment: Then you need them for more than "just display" and in that case you should not store them as a comma separated list - that violates the most basic principles of good database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are some valid reasons for storing lists as string data, if you need referential integrity, then yours is not one of those cases. Databases already have a feature that allows you store, and easily query lists, they are called tables.

So instead of using a comma separated list in the `Shop` table, you would use a [junction table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity) to store each item as its own row. Typically you would end up with a schema something like:

**Shop** (ShopID (PK), Name, etc)

**Product** (ProductID (PK), Name, etc)

**ShopProduct** (ShopID (PK, FK), ProductID (PK, FK))

This allows you to ensure that you avoid duplicates (if you so require), and ensure that each product is a valid one.

If you need a comma separated list at any point, you can create one, although how you would do this is very DMBS specific, and since you have not indicated one, I won't list all of the options, but `STRING_AGG` is one way of doing it (if your DMBS supports it):

```
SELECT  s.ShopID,
        s.Name AS ShopName,
        STRING_AGG(p.Name, ',') AS Products
FROM    Shop AS s
        INNER JOIN ShopProduct AS sp
            ON sp.ShopID = s.ShopID
        INNER JOIN Product AS p
            ON p.ProductID = sp.ProductID
GROUP By s.ShopID, s.Name;
```

Comment: The only sensible solution to the question

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about all of this! :)